# Adobe Flex fails on unicode / foreign input in Linux

Tags: apache-flex, unicode, input

I was learning flex for a few days now and suddenly noticed that input of unicode / foreign characters on **Linux** into **TextInput**, **TextArea** or **RichTextEditor** gives you unreadable text composed of several characters (seems like utf-8 is making things bad). On the other hand, output is flawless.

I was trying hard to find anything for the same issue on the internet, but only this old [blog entry](http://capitalhcoder.com/2007/11/11/unicode-foreign-character-entry-in-flex) could be seen. Author produced temporary solution but it is not sufficient.

So if Windows allows unicode and Linux doesn't, what should I do? Maybe the problem is on my machine only? Did anybody come up with the same problem and maybe the solution?

I have Adobe Flash 10.0.32.18 installed on my Sabayon Linux box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have something to do with this bug:

[Incorrect unicode input in linux](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-40)

Which, apparently, will get fixed once FP 10.1 is released.

Comment: Thank you! Have not looked at the Adobe bug site.

Answer (score 1):

Just to further update the answer. `Flex 4` components support unicode and the unicode characters can be typed into input controls using `Google Chrome`, `Firefox 3.6`+ and `IE7`+ .

For Java **MySQL** users

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

To allow utf8 data-write operations.

Database table and columns must be set to utf8_* encoding to make sure the unicode data can be stored in the tables.