# Unicode characters from Flex to Java

Tags: java, apache-flex, mate

I am using MATE Framework. I am using HTTPService to send data. While sending unicode characters from Flex to Java, I recieve garbage values in Java form. Can something be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

IN FLEX APP SET

```
System.useCodepage = true
```

for details see blog 
[Flex HTTPService - how to change character set of parameters](http://in-trace.blogspot.com/2008/11/flex-httpservice-how-to-change.html)

Also check character-set on you java side, and set

```
charset=UTF-8
```

for detaisl see link [Character Sets and Encodings](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebI18N5.html)

Hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623994/adobe-flex-fails-on-unicode-foreign-input-in-linux/4920231#4920231) for unicode datastore operations with mysql.